# How to move files into /usr/bin in Nautilus without getting permission errors

Tags: nautilus, permissions, gksu

I'm trying to move some files into `/usr/bin` in Nautilus but I'm getting permission errors. I know I can do it via the terminal using `sudo` but how can I do it in Nautilus? I would expect it to popup a box for me to enter my password like the admin screens in Ubuntu but it doesn't.

Comment: Moving files into `/usr/bin` is almost certainly wrong, if you need an application that is not packaged, and all users on the system should be able to use it, it should go into `/usr/local/bin` or in a directory under `/opt`.  If you are the only user who needs this application, you can also keep it in your personal directory.  Also see [`man hier`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man7/hier.7.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can  do it like this:

press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open the 'Run Application' box 
type `gksudo nautilus` in to the text box and press 'Enter'. This will prompt a password dialog box. Enter your sudo password and it will open nautilus with root privilege. From there you can move/copy files without any permission error.

*Note: Just make sure that you don't delete/replace any system files.*

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time, because I'm way to lazy to type
I assume you might just want to keep it visual like me.

Applications--> Accessories-->Terminal

```
$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for me: my_password
```

the gui file manager will pop up running like root

Be mighty careful :-)

Comment: Because 'nautilus' is a GUI (a Graphical User Interface), you should run it via **'gksu'** (or 'gksudo'), and not via 'sudo'... **'gksu'** sets up a specific environment for **'X'** (X Window System) ... 'sudo' is for programs, which have no graphical window(s)... ie. their output is confined to the Terminal, eg 'sudo updatedb'.... see the "Graphical sudo" section at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo where it says: "You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications .........

Answer (score 1):

Root Nautilus script. This script opens Nautilus as root in the directory you select.
how to install [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Root+Nautilus?content=126648)