# root in ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: permissions, root

i use ubuntu 14.04 LTS

my aim is to copy file called .bully to root on ubuntu but still told me that i don't have permission to do that even my account is administrative

so what can i do to have permession to past them

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Would opening a terminal and calling the following command be fine? `sudo cp .bully /`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get root access for copying files to /usr/share/...?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10435/get-root-access-for-copying-files-to-usr-share)

Answer (score 3):

Having an administrative account on a Linux machine doesn't mean that every command you execute is automatically run with full permissions. This would be unwise and may even make your system unusable.

To run a command with full access to the file system, you can add `sudo` before the command. This will run the following command as the actual root user, so it gains the needed permissions.

Example:

```
sudo cp .bully /
```

This would copy the file .bully to the root directory. This wouldn't work without sudo, as the root directory doesn't provide write access to anyone but the root user.

---

To include my comment into the answer: You should never run a program with administrative rights, if you don't know what you're actually doing. Before you start messing around, with sudo, I recommend you to at least learn the usage of the following comands by heart (including options):

```
ls, cd, cat, less, more, grep, rm, mv
```

If you can use these commands properly, you can accomplish many tasks from the termina. Only if you feel sure in using them, you should start doing administrative tasks with sudo. There's a nice game for learning to use Bash commands: [Terminus](http://web.mit.edu/mprat/Public/web/Terminus/Web/main.html)

Comment: my file which called .bully is in Desktop and i want to past it to root would you please give me the hole command

Comment: Do you mean the root directory or the home directory of the root user?

Comment: i don't know exactly but when i run bully he save the session in /root/.bully/fileonquestion.run

Comment: So .bully is a directory?

Comment: i don't know exactly but could you type them both and i try Sudoroot cp ./Desktop /home/root

Comment: First find out whether .bully is a direcory or not: `file ~/Desktop/.bully`. If it says directory, use this command: `sudo cp -R ~/Desktop/.bully /root`. If it says something else, use `sudo cp ~/Desktop/.bully /root`.

Comment: No offense, but if you don't even know how to use `cp`, you probably should keep your fingers off any command that involves `sudo`. Especially if you have no idea what the command actually does.