# Moving content into other directory

Tags: files, directory, copy

How to move content of one directory into another directory? I want to move content from 
`/Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1` 
into directory `/usr/local/bin/kafka`

I tried to move it using solutions found on the web but it doesnt work.

```
$ mv /Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1/* /usr/local/bin/kafka
```

produces error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1/*’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get root access for copying files to /usr/share/...?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10435/get-root-access-for-copying-files-to-usr-share)

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1/* /usr/local/bin/kafka
```

assuming you have your `Downloads` folder in your home directory.
Anyway you need to run it with `sudo` to move it to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: The problem might be that I as a user I want move content from my home directory    /Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1   into root  directory /usr/local/bin/kafka .

Comment: The problem might be that as a user I want move content from my home directory    /Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1   into root  directory /usr/local/bin/kafka . Im trying to use the command stated on the top, in my user home dir, Im not log in as root user.

Comment: So probably you can't move files to `/usr/local/bin/`, because usually only root users can.

Comment: Yes thats what I also thought, so if I log in as root user, what command should use?

Comment: `sudo mv /home/<your_username>/Downloads/kafka_2.11-1.0.1/* /usr/local/bin/kafka`

Comment: So I think you can mark that answer as correct :)

Answer (score -1):

You use it incorrectly. Try `mv kafva newdirectory`. Or you did specify directory path incorrectly, so it cannot find /Downloads/tra-ta-ta/*

Update: Are you really have Downloads in root directory? Either path is incorrect or you dont have enough permissions, use sudo mv ...

Comment: Yes I have Downloads dir and inside of that another directory kafka_2.11-1.0  .  Content of kafka_2.11-1.0 directory I want to move into existing root directory, the path for that dir is /usr/local/bin/kafka

Comment: Where you have "Downloads"? If it in home dir other answers is correct